# How to open the correct function implementation in RubyMine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

When I try opening a function implementation in RubyMine using cmd+click it shows multiple implementations, is there any way to narrow it down to the correct one.

Comment: Not really. Rubymine is probally just using pattern matching in your source code and gems. Since Ruby is an extremely dynamic language with boatloads of metaprogramming these kind of methods usually struggle. The only way to actually get a real answer is to run the code and inspect the method object - thats not really doable in a IDE as you would have to satisify all the dependencies of the code.

Comment: Its is doable by adding a breakpoint and doing it manually - `self.method(:method_name).source_location`.

Comment: @max "sometimes doable" :)